# Problemas con JsTree plugin [PHP/MYSQL]

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

he incorporado JSTree a mi proyecto segui un tutorial de como crear,renombrar y eliminar items de mi vista arbol con coneccion a mysql y utilizando php. el problema que me encontre es que los items del arbol se muestran con la columna de la tabla (text) en vez de (name). lo segundo que al momento de crear un nuevo elemento este no se guarda con el nombre que le asignamos, si no que se autonombra (New Node),lo mismo ocurre si le doy en renombrar el elemento.
**dejare una captura.**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

a continuacion les dejare los unicos 2 archivos PHP que utiliza para ejecutarla + la DB que solo la icorporan y listo(estara funcionando).

**index.php**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jstree/3.2.1/themes/default/style.min.css" />
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jstree/3.2.1/jstree.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    //fill data to tree  with AJAX call
    $('#tree-container').jstree({
        'core' : {
            'data' : {
                            'url' : 'response.php?operation=get_node',
                            'data' : function (node) {
                                return { 'id' : node.id };
                            },
                            "dataType" : "json"
                        }
            ,'check_callback' : true,
                        'themes' : {
                            'responsive' : false
                        }
            },
            'plugins' : ['state','contextmenu','wholerow']
        }).on('create_node.jstree', function (e, data) {

                    $.get('response.php?operation=create_node', { 'id' : data.node.parent, 'position' : data.position, 'text' : data.node.text })
                        .done(function (d) {
                            data.instance.set_id(data.node, d.id);
                        })
                        .fail(function () {
                            data.instance.refresh();
                        });
                }).on('rename_node.jstree', function (e, data) {
                    $.get('response.php?operation=rename_node', { 'id' : data.node.id, 'text' : data.text })
                        .fail(function () {
                            data.instance.refresh();
                        });
                }).on('delete_node.jstree', function (e, data) {
                    $.get('response.php?operation=delete_node', { 'id' : data.node.id })
                        .fail(function () {
                            data.instance.refresh();
                        });
                });
});
</script>

</head>
<body>
<div id="tree-container"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

**response.php**

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "nombreDB";

$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname) or die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}
if(isset($_GET['operation'])) {
    try {
        $result = null;
        switch($_GET['operation']) {
            case 'get_node':
                $node = isset($_GET['id']) && $_GET['id'] !== '#' ? (int)$_GET['id'] : 0;
                $sql = "SELECT * FROM `treeview_items` ";
                $res = mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die("database error:". mysqli_error($conn));
                if($res->num_rows <=0){
                 //add condition when result is zero
                } else {
                    //iterate on results row and create new index array of data
                    while( $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res) ) { 
                        $data[] = $row;
                    }
                    $itemsByReference = array();

                // Build array of item references:
                foreach($data as $key => &$item) {
                   $itemsByReference[$item['id']] = &$item;
                   // Children array:
                   $itemsByReference[$item['id']]['children'] = array();
                   // Empty data class (so that json_encode adds "data: {}" ) 
                   $itemsByReference[$item['id']]['data'] = new StdClass();
                }

                // Set items as children of the relevant parent item.
                foreach($data as $key => &$item)
                   if($item['parent_id'] && isset($itemsByReference[$item['parent_id']]))
                      $itemsByReference [$item['parent_id']]['children'][] = &$item;

                // Remove items that were added to parents elsewhere:
                foreach($data as $key => &$item) {
                   if($item['parent_id'] && isset($itemsByReference[$item['parent_id']]))
                      unset($data[$key]);
                }
                }
                $result = $data;
                break;
            case 'create_node':
                $node = isset($_GET['id']) && $_GET['id'] !== '#' ? (int)$_GET['id'] : 0;

                $nodeText = isset($_GET['text']) && $_GET['text'] !== '' ? $_GET['text'] : '';
                $sql ="INSERT INTO `treeview_items` (`name`, `text`, `parent_id`) VALUES('".$nodeText."', '".$nodeText."', '".$node."')";
                mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

                $result = array('id' => mysqli_insert_id($conn));
                print_r($result);die;
                break;
            case 'rename_node':
                $node = isset($_GET['id']) && $_GET['id'] !== '#' ? (int)$_GET['id'] : 0;
                //print_R($_GET);
                $nodeText = isset($_GET['text']) && $_GET['text'] !== '' ? $_GET['text'] : '';
                $sql ="UPDATE `treeview_items` SET `name`='".$nodeText."',`text`='".$nodeText."' WHERE `id`= '".$node."'";
                mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
                break;
            case 'delete_node':
                $node = isset($_GET['id']) && $_GET['id'] !== '#' ? (int)$_GET['id'] : 0;
                $sql ="DELETE FROM `treeview_items` WHERE `id`= '".$node."'";
                mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
                break;
            default:
                throw new Exception('Unsupported operation: ' . $_GET['operation']);
                break;
        }
        header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
        echo json_encode($result);
    }
    catch (Exception $e) {
        header($_SERVER["SERVER_PROTOCOL"] . ' 500 Server Error');
        header('Status:  500 Server Error');
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
    die();
}


?>
```

**y la por ultimo la DB**

```
-- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
-- version 4.9.2
-- https://www.phpmyadmin.net/
--
-- Servidor: 127.0.0.1
-- Tiempo de generación: 13-02-2020 a las 14:05:17
-- Versión del servidor: 10.4.11-MariaDB
-- Versión de PHP: 7.2.26

SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET AUTOCOMMIT = 0;
START TRANSACTION;
SET time_zone = "+00:00";


/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8mb4 */;

--

--

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Estructura de tabla para la tabla `treeview_items`
--

CREATE TABLE `treeview_items` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `text` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `parent_id` varchar(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Volcado de datos para la tabla `treeview_items`
--

INSERT INTO `treeview_items` (`id`, `name`, `text`, `parent_id`) VALUES
(1, 'numero1', 'task1title', '0'),
(2, 'numero 2', 'task2title', '1'),
(3, 'numero3', 'task1title3', '1'),
(4, 'numero4', 'task2title4', '3'),
(5, 'numero5', 'task1title4', '3'),
(6, 'task5', 'task2title5', '5'),
(7, 'task42', 'desc', '2'),
(8, 'task45', 'desc', '2'),
(9, 'task56', 'desc', '2'),
(10, 'task87', 'desc', '5'),
(11, 'task66', 'desc', '3');

--
-- Índices para tablas volcadas
--

--
-- Indices de la tabla `treeview_items`
--
ALTER TABLE `treeview_items`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT de las tablas volcadas
--

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT de la tabla `treeview_items`
--
ALTER TABLE `treeview_items`
  MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=12;
COMMIT;

/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
```

ojala alguen me pueda ayudar de ante mano muchas gracias.